# Custom marketing automation activity does not work in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: marketing-automation

I've created and successfully tested custom activity type in Sitecore 9.0.0 according to this guide:
https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/marketing-automation/activities/activity-types/add-activity-type-to-ui.html

But when I deploy exactly the same code to Sitecore 9.0.1 and click on my custom action, JavaScript error occurs:

> vendor.6be6958dbf1b66c98060.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in
>   promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'map' of null
>       at de (vendor.6be6958dbf1b66c98060.bundle.js:1)
>       at _n (vendor.6be6958dbf1b66c98060.bundle.js:1)
>       at l.dn (vendor.6be6958dbf1b66c98060.bundle.js:1)
>       at View_ReadonlyEditorComponent_Host_0 (readonly-editor.component.ngfactory.ts:37)

I've also tried out a few examples from blog posts, i.e. https://www.brimit.com/blog/sitecore-marketing-automation-creating-activity-editor but none of them works on Sitecore 9.0.1, all of them fail with exact same error when I click on action and editor loads.

Has anyone managed to get custom activity type working on Sitecore 9.0.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked birmit's blog, actually you have to update angular dependency to 5.

package.json is =>

```
{
  "name": "demo9.features.sendemailpromo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Sitecore 9 Marketing Automation Demo",
  "private": true,
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "predev": "npm install && rimraf ./codegen/",
    "dev": "ngc -p ./src/tsconfig.aot.json && npm run build",
    "prebuild": "rimraf ./dist/",
    "build": "webpack --display-error-details"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.1",
    "@sitecore/ma-core": "file:C:/Website/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/MarketingAutomation/packages/ma-core",
    "rxjs": "5.5.8",
    "zone.js": "0.8.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
    "copyfiles": "2.0.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.2",
    "ts-loader": "4.1.0",
    "typescript": "2.8.1",
    "webpack": "4.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13"
  }
}
```

also change the module to es2015 to commonJs in tscinfig.aot.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "../codegen",
        "rootDir": "",
        "declaration": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2016",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! That's a really weird one, I'd expect ma-core package to have references to Angular 5 too, but in 9.0.1 it still points to 4.